# Can I share a maven repository between maven 2 and maven 3

Tags: maven, maven-2, repository, maven-3

Can I have multiple Maven instances i.e Mave 2.2.1 and Maven 3 both point to the same local repository?

I mean I know I can technically point each settings.xml to the same folder but will this cause me any hardships in the long run?  Or is it advised?

Comment: Do you mean in parallel? With parallel concurrent builds? Than the answer is no. Otherwise you can use a repo with Maven 2 and Maven 3.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend it.  Maven 2 and 3 handle artifact metadata differently.  Also, Maven 3 forces the use of timestamped snapshots while Maven 2 leaves it as an option.  We have development teams that have tried the mixed Maven version use and they end up with a mess in the remote artifact repo, I'm guessing the same would be true for local as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; this is the default behaviour of Maven 2 and 3. In general, keeping both using the default of `~/.m2/repository` will work fine, although there are a few edge case documented in the [Maven 3.x Compatibility Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes).

In particular, see Snapshot Updates, Unique Snapshot Versions and Classifiers and Resolution from Local Repository for more information.

Comment: Switching from M2 to M3 is painless. IIRC the main issue is when pulling snapshots from a remote repository, which will be stored in slightly different metadata format. The rest should be fine.